# Calculations of compound gears?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, transmission

Recently I've been scratching my head over an assignment, and I have trouble understanding a couple of the parts.
[image: Sketch]

The issue I have is with the overall calculations, since we've just started on mechanical issues and I have no experience except easy transmissions. Therefor, I am wondering how I calculate the ratio of the compound gear between A and B, and how many turns the worm gear have to turn to make the C spur gear travel a specified distance of 100mm.

The question goes as follows;

> How many revolutions does the worm gear have to complete, for the
>   spring to compress entirely?

The C gear is connected to a rack that then compresses a spring, that'll have to travel 100mm.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for a tooth on C to travel 100mm, the teeth on B also need to travel 100mm. Let's not worry about how many revolutions that is.

A has 2.6 times as many teeth as B,and travels the same number of rotations, so, that means that a tooth on A must travel 260mm.

The pitch of the worm is 4mm, so, it needs to rotate 260/4=65 times in order to cause the teeth if A to move 260mm, and consequently the teeth of the rack meshed with C 100mm